# UIScrollView automatically scrolls down during pinch in?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have uiscrollview and added an image view to it. When I pinch in scroll view i can able to zoom in but the scroll view automatically scrolls down a bit. So that I'm not able to zoom the bottom portion of uiimageview.

```
    UIScrollView *scroll = [[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    scroll.minimumZoomScale = 1.0f;
    scroll.maximumZoomScale = 16.0f;
    scroll.delegate = self;

 [scroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(scroll.frame.size.width, scroll.frame.size.height+2200)];
scroll.frame = self.view.frame;
[scroll setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
[self.view addSubview:scroll];


UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
[img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
[img setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_button.jpg"]];
[img setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 200)];
[img setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
[scroll addSubview:img];



- (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
    return [[scrollView subviews] firstObject];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you're using a UIPinchGestureRecognizer for your pinch event...

What you want to do is add these "if" statements at the beginning and end of your method:

```
- (void)handlePinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        self.scrollView.enabled = NO;

    // pinch handling here

    if ((sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) || (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled))
        self.scrollView.enabled = YES;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using UIScrollView Which Got its default Pinch gesture action.             - (UIView*)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView                {
    return [[scrollView subviews] firstObject];
}

Comment: From what you're describing in the OP, I think you want to apply the UIPinchGestureRecognizer to the UIImageView, not to the UIScrollView.

Comment: @ Tim Kokesh UiscrollView got UIPinchGestureRecognizer by default So i preferred using it . And Also how can I crop main image that appears in Crop Rect.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code, this might be helpful

```
   - (void) pinchView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)pinchGestureRecognizer
    {
        UIView *view = self.showImgView;
        if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
            view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(view.transform, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale, pinchGestureRecognizer.scale);
            pinchGestureRecognizer.scale = 1;
        }
        else if (pinchGestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
            CGRect newFrame = self.showImgView.frame;
            newFrame = [self handleScaleOverflow:newFrame];
            newFrame = [self handleBorderOverflow:newFrame];
            [UIView animateWithDuration:BOUNDCE_DURATION animations:^{
                self.showImgView.frame = newFrame;
                self.latestFrame = newFrame;
            }];
        }
    }
```